# Selecting rows out of a column that contain a certain string in R

Tags: r

I have a data set of a group of college with various names such as "x college" "x university" and "x community college" and need to group them by their classification of college, community college, or university.

And then organizing them by state. There are 5 rows: Name, Location, two types of tuition, and private or public.

I have tried this:
typeSchool <- c("College", "University", "Community College")
filter(tibble, str_detect(words, paste(typeSchool)))

But it has not worked. Looking for suggestions.

Should I try mutating variables and adding a separate variable for each classification and then group_by(classification)?

Sample Rows:

Also would it be possible to use a form of grep for this?

---

```
structure(list(Name = structure(c(5L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Bard College",
```

"Brown University", "Connecticut College", "Dartmouth College", 
"Landmark College", "St. John's College"), class = "factor"), 
    Location = structure(c(5L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("ANNANDALE-ON-HUDSON, NY", 
    "HANOVER, NH", "NEW LONDON, CT", "PROVIDENCE, RI", "PUTNEY, VT", 
    "SANTA FE, NM"), class = "factor"), In.State.Tuition = c(50080L, 
    49906L, 49644L, 49506L, 49350L, 49346L), Out.of.State.Tuition = c(50080L, 
    49906L, 49644L, 49506L, 49350L, 49346L), Type = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Private", class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: The issue is that 'words' is not a column name in your dataset.  Not sure which column you are trying.  `Name` is one column that have the 'College' substring.  So, insted of 'word', should change it to 'Name'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `collapse` with `|` to create a single string to be used as `pattern` in `str_detect`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
filter(tibble, str_detect(Name, paste(typeSchool, collapse = "|")))
```

To make sure that this won't match any substrings, we can use the word boundary (`\\b`)

```
filter(tibble, str_detect(Name, paste0("\\b(", paste(typeSchool, collapse = "|"), ")\\b")))
```

---

As we are already using `stringr`, an option is `str_c` which would be helpful if there are missing values as it returns `NA` when any value is NA as opposed to `paste` which will paste the NA also in the string

```
filter(tibble, str_detect(Name,  str_c(typeSchool, collapse = "|")))
```

#### Update

If the intention is to split or create multiple datasets based on the 'typeSchool', we can `map` over the 'typeSchool', `filter` the rows based on the substring match to return a `list` of tibbles

```
library(purrr)
lst1 <-  map(typeSchool, ~  tibble %>% 
             filter(str_detect(Name, .x)))
```

Comment: Tried this and got the error: > filter(tibble, str_detect(words, paste(typeSchool, collapse = "|")))
Error: Result must have length 400, not 980

May this be the difference between the College and Community College classification?

Comment: @RocketRefs can you show few rows of the tibble object with `dput` so that i can test it.  It should work actually

Comment: There are 400 rows of 5 variables but the first few rows of names look like this: 
".Label = c("Academy College", "Adelphi University", 
"Agnes Scott College", "AIB College of Business", "Akron Institute of Herzing University", 
"Alabama A & M University", "Alabama State University", "Albertus Magnus College", 
"Alderson Broaddus University", "Alfred University", "Alice Lloyd College", 
"Allegheny Wesleyan College", "Allen College", "Alliant International University-San Diego", 
"American International College", "Amherst College", "Amridge University",

Comment: @RocketRefs is it possible to update your post with `dput(droplevels(head(tibble)))` so that i get the structure

Comment: I just added that to the original post.

Comment: @RocketRefs  you don't have a column named 'words'

Comment: @RocketRefs i guess you are looking to filter separately.  Can you check my update thanks

Comment: Yes I am looking to filter each separately. I'm supposed to have anything without "University" grouped with "College" since there are 17 of these instances that do not contain any of these three strings. I see your update though and the mapping does work along with actually putting the "Name" variable.

Comment: Should I create a factor to ensure that community colleges don't get thrown into the 'college' category and so that schools that don't have one of these three classifications get put in the 'college' category?
For example an "Institute"

Comment: @RocketRefs can you show some example of community college names does the community comes as prefix always?

Comment: It does not. So for example in lst1[1] it still classifies the community colleges as college, and there are 17 variables excluded out of the 400 altogether. Some of the community college names are "Butler County Community College" or "Community College of Beaver County", but then some are "Delaware Technical Community College-Stanton/Wilmington" so adding a before/after restriction wouldn't change much.

Comment: @RocketRefs one option is to first filter out the `Community` college i.e. `df2 <- tibble %>% filter(str_detect(Name, 'Community'))` and for the `map` part use the ones without `Community i.le. `map(typeSchool, ~  tibble %>%  filter(str_detect(Name, .x), !str_detect(Name, 'Community')))`

Comment: That is a good solution. Do you have any idea how to add the ones that don't contain any of the three variables and add them to the 'college'  list?

Comment: @RocketRefs For that you can use `filter(tibble, !str_detect(Name, paste(typeSchool, collapse = "|")))`

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you very much for your help. Instead, I just created the variables for University and Community College and then excluded those two factors from the single 'college' variable.
I also did upvote your solution but I don't have 15 reputation so it will not show. Thakn you.